# Error when I set the color of an GridView Row when a column has a specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to set the gridview row color if a specific column has a value. But I got an error about nullreference in my DIVSTATUS.

My ASPX

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>                
                <div style="width:70px;" id="divStatus" runat="server"><%# Eval("DscStatus")%></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

My Code-Behind

```
                if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HtmlContainerControl divstatus = (HtmlContainerControl)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("divstatus");
                            if (divstatus != null)
                            {
                                if (divstatus.InnerText == "Andamento Project")
                                {
                                    GridView1.Rows[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
                                    GridView1.Rows[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                                }
                            }
                    }
              }
```

My Rendered HTML

```
<td>
     <div style="width:70px;">Andamento Project</div>
</td>
```

Comment: I think you should set them in `Row Databound` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `RowDataBound`  property and do code as below ...you dont need to get the div status you just get your datatype and in that datatype you get the value of your property by using than value of property you can decide the color of you row

```
protected void grdCAPRate_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       yourtype obj=  (yourtype)e.Row.DataItem;

           if (obj.DscStatus == "Andamento Project")    
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
          else
           e.Row.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.White;                                 

     }                
}
```

Comment: When my user click in the button, I call my 'loadGrid' method. In this method I put my code. How can I do that without RowDataBound Event ? With RowDataBound I think will be very slow because I have a lot of data in my GridView.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos - hey than your code is ok if possible make use of lable control ...and se the text value of lable rather than div..

Comment: I will try with the label. Let me try.

Comment: Doesn't work. I think this is becaus I do the databind on my GridView and in the same method I try to found the value of the label. The only way is via OnRowDataBound ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos - hey i dont know more about your code but i think its better to go for rowdatabound in such kind of senario

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HtmlContainerControl divstatus = (HtmlContainerControl) e.Row.FindControl("divstatus");
            if (divstatus != null)
            {
                if (divstatus.InnerText == "Andamento Project")
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Navy;
                    e.Row.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When my user click in the button, I call my 'loadGrid' method. In this method I put my code. How can I do that without RowDataBound Event ? With RowDataBound I think will be very slow because I have a lot of data in my GridView.

Comment: I tried your code. Your code is running without error. You check properly your code with using Debug. There must be something overlooked.